# Default credentials fail for Virtuoso

Tags: password

I have `virtuoso-opensource` version 6.1.6+repack-0ubuntu5 (installed on xenial 16.04.1 LTS).

Everything looks good, except the default logins for "dba" and "dav" do not work, in either the Virtuoso Conductor or in `isql-vt`.

The error from `isql-vt` is

> *** Error 28000: [Virtuoso Driver]CL034: Bad login

How do I log in?  (The package already changed `isql` to `isql-vt`... Did the distribution also change the default passwords?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an old install from over a year ago that I'd forgotten about.  Even though I tried an uninstall/reinstall, it preserved the data files (which makes sense) and I had no memory of changing the default password back then.

I moved the data directory aside (`mv /var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1 virtuoso-opensource-6.1.old`) and reinstalled, and then all worked as expected.

Additionally, I found that according to [this message](https://www.mail-archive.com/virtuoso-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07470.html), the company apparently can also provide instructions for a hard password reset.